# IE7 and IE8 css div box fake view?

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

please see below link and help me to fix this problem.

http://parsegard.com

my problem occur in IE6,7,8.
in fire fox you will see the page like this:

[image: ff]

but in IE6,7,or 8 we will see different face!
let me show in below picture:

[image: ie]

what should I do to fix this problem?

Comment: It would help if you described the problem in the question instead of requiring people to trawl your site's code.

Comment: this page designed before by another person and I must fix it for IE 6,7. to describe my problem must copy/paste all the code in question?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

those divs that contains your text seems to miss the width property, internet explorer makes the width of that div depending on how much text you got in those divs. try to set a max-width of 100%(or how much pixels you want) to the headerCenter div or/and boxTitle btlink div. this might help you.

Comment: thanks for your replay.
but I did it and it doesn't work! I have not access to  assign pixel value because this 2 or 3 block are same block with different content form CMS and unfortunately I must use percent...

Comment: you are welcome, but I really want to know if this helped you. And if it did, just check the answer as accepted so it won't appear in "Unanswered" posts.

Comment: so you are saying that you haven't worked it out? you still get that error? I am in linux now and can not check in explorer, but I 'll move to windows later and I'll have a look at it.